# Debug в OpenGL средствами glDebugMessageCallback

Tags: linux, opengl, отладка

Нет вывода лога от callback функции как решить проблему ?!

1. Платформа: Ubuntu 16.04
2. Drivers: Nvidea 361.42

Дебаг флаг для GL включён

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_FLAG);
```

Процедура вызова лога

```
    GLint flags;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flags);
    if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT) //Проверка на корректную инициализацию дебаг контекста(пройдено успешно)
    {
        SDL_Log("OpenGL debug \n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_Log("NOT OpenGL debug \n");
    }


if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_DEBUG_BIT)
            {
                glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
                glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
                glDebugMessageCallback(openglCallbackFunction, nullptr);
                glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, nullptr, GL_TRUE);
            }
            else
                SDL_Log("glDebugMessageCallback not available");
```

CallBack-функция вот она и не вызывается !!!

```
void openglCallbackFunction(GLenum source,
                            GLenum type,
                            GLuint id,
                            GLenum severity,
                            GLsizei length,
                            const GLchar* message,
                            const void* userParam)

{
    // ignore non-significant error/warning codes
    //Нет я уже сюда смотрел это здесь не причём
    if(id == 131169 || id == 131185 || id == 131218 || id == 131204) return;

    SDL_Log("---------------");
    SDL_Log("Debug message (%d ) %s \n",id,message);

    switch (source)
    {
    case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API:
        SDL_Log("Source: API");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM:
        SDL_Log("Source: Window System");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER:
        SDL_Log("Source: Shader Compiler");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY:
        SDL_Log("Source: Third Party");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION:
        SDL_Log("Source: Application");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER:
        SDL_Log("Source: Other");
        break;
    }
    SDL_Log("\n");

    switch (type)
    {
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR:
        SDL_Log("Type: Error");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR:
        SDL_Log("Type: Deprecated Behaviour");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR:
        SDL_Log("Type: Undefined Behaviour");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY:
        SDL_Log("Type: Portability");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE:
        SDL_Log("Type: Performance");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_MARKER:
        SDL_Log("Type: Marker");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PUSH_GROUP:
        SDL_Log("Type: Push Group");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_POP_GROUP:
        SDL_Log("Type: Pop Group");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER:
        SDL_Log("Type: Other");
        break;
    }
    SDL_Log("\n");

    switch (severity)
    {
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH:
        SDL_Log("Severity: high");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM:
        SDL_Log("Severity: medium");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW:
        SDL_Log("Severity: low");
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_NOTIFICATION:
        SDL_Log("Severity: notification");
        break;
    }
    SDL_Log("\n");
    SDL_Log("\n");

}
```

Comment: Какой версии контекст создаётся в вашей программе? Может быть у вас нет ошибок и callback не вызвается?

Comment: вообщем и целом я затеял это чтобы пройти тесты apitrace и он выявил ошибки в по но GL не видит их...
Вроде 4,3 версия